# How can I set the default value of my tkinter Scale widget slider to 100?

Tags: python, tkinter, slider, tkinter-scale

How can I set the default value of my slider to 100 ?

```
self.slider = tk.Scale(self.leftFrame, from_=0, to=256, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=updateValue)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cursor=100`[?](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm)

If that doesn't work, you can always manually `self.slider.set(100)`.

Comment: This answer is probably outdated. See official API: https://tkdocs.com/pyref/ttk_scale.html

Answer (score 6):

## 1. Set

Use the `set` method 
[1](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/scale.htm#Tkinter.Scale.set-method)
[2](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/scale.htm#M28)
: `self.scale.set(100)`

## 2. Variable

Use the `variable` option 
[3](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#patterns)
[4](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/scale.htm#M19)
 to assign a `Variable`
[5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#coupling-widget-variables)
[6](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/variable.htm)
[7](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Variable-class.html)

```
self.scale_var = DoubleVar()
self.scale_var.set(1)
self.scale = tk.Scale(self.leftFrame, from_=0, to=256, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
    command=updateValue, variable=self.scale_var)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.slider= tk.Scale(self.leftFrame, from_=0, to=256,orient=tk.HORIZONTAL,
command=updateValue)
self.slider.set(1)//or what ever value you want
self.slider.pack()
```

first give a name to scale then use set with value and at last pack()

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).